# C++ Link external libraries

Tags: c++, ice

i just started with c++ programming.
For my new work, i have to download, install and take use of an external library. It is called ICE.
It was composed as a .tar file, so i decomposed it inside my home-directory "/home/foo/ice".
Now, there is the directory: "/home/foo/ice/src", within all the .h headers, i need for the program.
But can i tell the compiler, where he can find all these new headers?
I mean only with #include, he obviously doesn't know.

What i need:

```
#include <image.h>
```

"image.h" is inside "/home/foo/ice/src"

Greetings

Comment: Libraries usually come with documentation which will tell you how to install it. (Usually something like `./configure && make && sudo make install`).

Comment: And compilers also usually come with documentation how to set a "include file search path". (Usually `-I<directory>`.)

Comment: You need to say which compiler, but I'll take a stab in the dark that it is `g++` or `clang`. Then you use `-I /directory/path` to say where to find `#include`s, `-L /d/p` to find libraries, and `-l ice` to link `libice.a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have gcc compiler you can use -I option.

From the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) :

> -I dir: Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.

So for you it should be something like this:

```
g++ myprog.cpp -I /home/foo/ice/src -o myprog
```

But it is better to install the library, you should have some readme.txt or INSTALL file about how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

You asked about *linking* a library, but your description shows that you have problems with the include path, which klm123 answered already.

The library paths for linking is another option, usually `-L`*`libpath`*
It may help to check the options of you compiler, here for example the [Directory Options of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)